# How to use portrait / landscape states in Flex 4.5 skin files

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder, flash-cs5, flex-mobile

In Flex 4.5 for mobile how can I use portrait / landscape states from a skin file?

e.g. In the skin file I want to create the following states

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="portrait" />
    <s:State name="landscape" />
</s:states>
```

and use them in the normal way. However the current state in the skin file is not updated when I switch between landscape and portrait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to bind to the current state of the host component:

```
<fx:Binding source="hostComponent.currentState" destination="this.currentState"/>
```

Also see this for an example:

```
http://saturnboy.com/2009/09/flex4-component-states-skin-states/
```